# Is it possible using PHP to backup SQL without dependecies? If not, which is the best?

Tags: php, mysql

After a huge MySQL blunder on a production server (my fault, and yes I have learned), I am now looking at creating a dump of the MySQL database before I do a critical operation (about 15 queries to the db, insert/update/selects). I know phpMyAdmin can 'dump' the database to SQL queries, but I think this may be a feature of it, not a feature of MySQL?

So, is there a way to do this using MySQL, and if not (which I suspect), what would be the best way to dump the db to a file on the server on command? Preferably as a tarball of the whole DB in ready to import SQL format.

Thank You!

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136269/best-way-to-backup-mysql-data-on-linux-server/

Comment: @Till It's not really a duplicate.. my question is PHP specific and is dealing with databases of any size, not just larger ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for the [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) function, I believe:

```
mysqldump my_database > database.dump
```

Answer (score 2):

MySQL dump will do it, and you can pipe it to gzip so it stores better:

```
mysqldump --opt -Q -h[server] -u[username] -p[password] [dbname] | gzip > [file].sql.gz
```

And to restore you unzip it and:

```
mysql -h[server] -u[username] -p[password] [dbname] < [file].sql
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used this for a few years now, why re-create the wheel :)

http://worldcommunity.com/opensource

Comment: If the one line solution works, I'd hardly call that reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Another good route is to use something like [sqlyog](http://webyog.com/en/) to automate backups.  I run this on a local Windows machine I have to do backups of all my remote servers.